# AJAX inside if statement

Tags: javascript, ajax, vbscript, asp-classic

This is my `onclick` function. The code without the `if` statement runs perfectly. I'm trying to test if `sbmt` is equal to 1 and only then remove the row. But once I add the `if` statement, the row cannot be removed. What is wrong with my code?

```js
function taskOnclick(row,task) {
    var url = 'remove_task.asp?task='+task;

    if (<%=("SBMT")%> === 1){ 
        $(this).row.closest('tr').remove();
        $.ajax({url: url, success: function(result){
            alert(result);
        }});
    }
};
```

```vb
<tr id="taskid">
        <%
            If objRS("REAS") <> "" Then
                strReason = "<br/><br/><b style=""color: red"">Reason: "&objRS("REAS")&"</b>"
            Else
                strReason = ""
            End If
            Response.Write "<td onclick=""taskOnclick(this,'"&objRS("TASK")&"')""><a href=""#"">" & objRS("TASK") & "<span>"&objRS("REMK")& strReason & "</span></a></td>"
            Response.write "<td>" & objRS("DDAT") & "</td>"
            Response.write "<td class=""days"" style=""text-align:center"">" & objRS("DAYS") & "</td>"
            Response.write "<td >" & objRS("CDAT") & "</td>"


        %>
</tr>
```

**UPDATED**

```
function taskOnclick(row,task) {
    var url = 'remove_task.asp?task='+task;
    var SBMT = <%=objRS("SBMT")%>;

if (SBMT == '1'){ 
    row.closest('tr').remove();

$.ajax({url: url, success: function(result){
    alert(result);
}});
}
else if (SBMT == '0'){
    alert("NO");
}
};
```

**SQL**

```
strWhere = " where acti= '1' "
    strSQL = "select task,ddat,ddat-trunc(sysdate) as days,prog,pnam,remk,reas,nvl(to_char(cdat,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'INPG') as cdat,sbmt from task" & strWhere
    strSQL = strSQL & "order by prog,ddat"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
if (<%=("SBMT")%> === 1){
```

is going to be written to your document as the following JavaScript:

```
if (SBMT === 1){
```

JavaScript is going to assume that `SBMT` is a JavaScript variable and test it to see if its value is strictly equal to `1`. I don't see a JavaScript variable with this name defined in your code, so this is going to cause the following error when your JavaScript runs:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SBMT is not defined

and, therefore, the contents of your `if` block will never be executed.

Comment: thank you sincerely!! i have updated..the if else still not run.@bond

Comment: Well, you're missing a semicolon on `var SBMT = <%=objRS("SBMT")%>`. It should be `var SBMT = <%=objRS("SBMT")%>;`.

Comment: use a debugger, look at the value of the variable

Comment: Just look at the page source once your page is loaded. If you don't see `var SBMT = 1;` then your recordset value is not what you're expecting.

Comment: what does this mean? @Bond

Comment: It means your database record has a value of `0`.

Comment: so i nid to put else statement right? ya u r right..my database got 1 and 0 @Bond

Comment: @bond i updated again..but this time it's keep alert 'No', that's mean all the sbmt is '0' ? but some is '1'..

Comment: Your problem isn't in the code above, so I can't help you. You'll need to determine why you're only retrieving database records with `0` values. You may want to open a new ticket for that and show your database/SQL code.

Comment: Honestly @Bond I wouldn't have bothered.